# Strptime adding a '1' to the end of the timestamp

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, strptime

This is a really stupid problem in R but I don't know how to fix it. I'm having the following code:

```
library(lubridate)
options(digits.secs = 3)

start <- strptime("2013-12-10 01:59:26.901", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Chicago")
end <- strptime("2013-12-10 01:59:27.729", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Chicago")
```

When I do `end - start` I expect the output to be `0.828` seconds but instead I get `0.8280001`.

**EDIT**: [I know why it happens now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal), but not how to fix it. How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix it is to round the result to the precision you expect.  This can be done by modifying the value, or just formatting the output.  For example,

```
round(end - start, 3)
```

will print `Time difference of 0.828 secs`.

A difficulty with this approach is that you might not know the original precision of the values, e.g. if `start` and `end` came from a different program.  There's really no good solution in that case.

Another possibility is to format the difference; then it will be printed the way you want, but not changed.  For example,

```
format(end-start, digits = 3)
```

which produces `0.828 secs`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My problem isn't really with the rounding of `end - start` but I need the timestamps to be correct. Eventually I want to filter my data with the timestamps, but the filtering gets the wrong result as something is not entirely correct in the timestamps.

Comment: If it's just for filtering, I would use the formatting approach.  Don't test if the value is equal to `0.828`, test if the formatted value is equal to `"0.828"`.  (Add `" secs"` or whatever if necessary.)